# Retrieve all molecules from smiles file

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, cheminformatics

I am working on .smiles files. File structure of .smiles file is : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_file_format#SMILES

I want to get all the atoms from the smiles file. It means that If there is single 'C' atom it means that there will be 4 'H' atoms will be connected to them.

I found while searching that there are some modules in python which can parse the smiles format but they do not give the supported hydrogen atoms. (for example : they only give 'C' and not other 4 'H' atoms connected to that 'C' atom)

How can I find all the atoms including the connected 'H' atoms as well using python.
Example of smiles file which needs to be converted in to all atoms including connected 'H' atoms:

```
[H]OC([H])([H])[C@@]1([H])C([H])=C([H])[C@@]([H])(n2c([H])nc3c(nc(nc23)N([H])[H])N([H])C2([H])C([H])([H])C2([H])[H])C1([H])[H]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it's actually better to ask this question in bluobelisk http://blueobelisk.shapado.com/

Answer (score 6):

See [Open Babel](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Useful Links on Open Babel Site

- "[Guides](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Category%3aGuides)"
- [Capabilities](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Capabilities)
- [Using Python with Open Babel](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Python)
- [Other tools](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Tutorial%3aOther_Tools), includes a tool ([obprop](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Obprop))

See Also,
[This blog](http://pythonchem.blogspot.in/) (by Casper Steinmann) on Chemistry with Python (using Open Babel, not all though)

**Update**
See this code(untested):

```
mymol = pybel.readstring("smi",  
"[H]OC([H])([H])[C@@]1([H])C([H])=C([H])[C@@]([H])(n2c([H])nc3c(nc(nc23)" + \
"N([H])[H])N([H])C2([H])C([H])([H])C2([H])[H])C1([H])[H")
print mymol.addh()
```

Comment: is this the output you want? `OC[C@H]1C=C[C@@H](n2cnc3c(nc(nc23)N)NC2CC2)C1 
`

Answer (score 3):

*I want to get all the atoms from the smiles file. It means that If there is single 'C' atom it means that there will be 4 'H' atoms will be connected to them.*
This assumption is not correct, it can be 1,2,3 hydrogens.

Try, openbabel, CDK or similar library for cheminformatics.

But, why do you need all atoms from the file?

Comment: i want because i want to find the atomic weight from it. i also want to find out donor and acceptors.

Comment: @sam He (sam) seems to want the atomic mass of the most stable atomic configration(not the right word here). If that's the case, 1 'C' will have to bond with 4 'H', to be stable. Is that so sam?...

Comment: yes but that 4 H does not be present in the smiles file format. so i have to calculate such H and then i want to calculate the mass.

Comment: openbabel have python bindings (pybel) and also CDK - http://pycdk.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

For the molecular weight of a compound, given as SMILES, the Python bindings of Openbabel  should work:

```
import pybel
mol = pybel.readfile("smi", "stuff.smi").next()
print mol.molwt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [frowns](http://frowns.sourceforge.net/), a chemoinformatics toolkit geared toward rapid development of chemistry related algorithms.  It is written in almost 100% Python with a small portion written in C++.

Comment: frowns seems to only be for Python 2.2(old), and it also needs vflib(not a problem). Also, the project seems dead since 2004(old,Big Problem).

Answer (score 0):

[RDKIT](http://www.rdkit.org) is a well defined cheminformatics library in python.

To read a molecule from smiles,

```
from rdkit import Chem

m = Chem.MolFromSmiles('[H]OC([H])([H])[C@@]1([H])C([H])=C([H])[C@@]([H])(n2c([H])nc3c(nc(nc23)N([H])[H])N([H])C2([H])C([H])([H])C2([H])[H])C1([H])[H]')
```

After you read in the smiles into an RDKIT molecule you can pretty much do everything. documentation - http://www.rdkit.org